# Managing the domain path for different environments

Tags: angular, angular-router

We have the current domains with a legacy frontend.

- Dev:     localhost/client-name-1
- Staging: staging-site.our-domain.com/client-name-1
- Prod:    client-name-1.our-domain.com

Having moved to angular our dev looks like:

- Dev:     http://localhost:4200

We are using angular router and this would suggest i need to add a route for the client slug however this route does not exist in prod, so how should this be managed ?

Comment: Check out base href https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this during build please try with these command

```
ng serve --base-href /client-name-1/
```

After this command you will access your project locally: http://localhost:4200/client-name-1/

```
ng build --base-href /client-name-1/
```

Comment: Our infrastructure setup doesn't allow for environment specific builds. The CI builds a single prod version and config specific to environment / client is added when deployed to a server.